How do change animation fade out time in OneShot animation?
I am new to Godot, just started using the engine, I have some experience coding and making things in C# and Unity.
I am trying to make a simple jump animation for a Mixamo character but I am encountering  a problem. I do not know how to blend the animation back into the moving state after I OneShot the jumping animation and it ends.

The transition is not smooth at the end of the jumping animation. For that I tried to use AnimationNodeOneShot.ONE_SHOT_REQUEST_FADE_OUT, after I did this, i realized that the animation is not played anymore, maybe because the animation fade out time is too long? That's why i looked for a method to change the fade out time and I found this in the documentation but the problem is I have no idea how to use it.

How do I use this?
Here is the simple function that I made for starting the animation
How can I use AnimationNodeOneShot.ONE_SHOT_REQUEST_FADE_OUT properly?
func _jump(jump_state : JumpState):
    animation_tree["parameters/" + jump_state.animation_name + "/request"] = AnimationNodeOneShot.ONE_SHOT_REQUEST_FIRE
    #animation_tree["parameters/" + jump_state.animation_name + "/request"] = AnimationNodeOneShot.ONE_SHOT_REQUEST_FADE_OUT

For further detail I am trying to reproduce this tutorial that I found on YouTube.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bTtptbkv4xw&t=6s
Thank you for anyone interested in helping me. I really appreciate it.
